# Referencing aggregate results via alias using CASE in select column specification

Tags: mysql, aggregate, alias

This is a piece of a much larger set of tables, but the bare breakdown is I have two tables, `employees` and `profits`. Every time profit is made in the company it is added to profits and references the employee ID that made the profit and I perform a case check to display an arbitrary value in a custom column.

Schema:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad19

When I pull a list of employees, I generate a total of all the profits belonging to them via a subquery:
`SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    (SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM`profits
    `WHERE profits.employee_id=employees.id) AS`profits
    `FROM employees`

Which yields the following columns:

`firstname
lastname
profits`

Now, I need to set a custom column to a value depending on the value of profits. If profits was a regular column in the employees table instead of the result of a sub-query I would simply do this:

`SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    (SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM`profits
    `WHERE profits.employee_id=employees.id) AS`profits
    `CASE
        WHEN (`profits`IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Met Requirements'
        WHEN (`profits`>100) THEN 'Exceeded Requirements'
        ELSE 'No Profits'
    END as rating
    FROM employees`

This as you can see creates a "rating" alias column in the result set which I can set conditionally based on whatever I feel I want to depending on how much, or if profits have occurred for the user. I am sending the result of this data to a third party app which we have no control over and simply displays the column "rating" as is, so I need it pre-populated with either "No profits" or "Met/Exceeded Requirements".

However, I was frustrated to find that you cant use CASE in this situation because it complains the rating column doesnt exist since it is inferred (or whatever word mysql uses for madeup columns)

Is there *any* way I can make this work?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Also, note that correlated subqueries can be slow on larger data sets.

Comment: Added schema. I do know that correlated subqueries can slow on large DBs, and I was originally going to add a tally to the employee table for amount which would be updated whenever profit was added, but heard screams of users that its "bad database design" to do tallies and it should be pulled via joins and sums.

How else would I get the total profit without doing a sub query or a tally in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 2):

The query you need is just a simple LEFT JOIN because you have to show every `employee` with their `profits`. Also you have a little mistake on your `case` statement `IS NOT NULL` will never let the `'No Profits'` condition to be true. So I fixed this, try this query:

```
select firstname,
       lastname,
       CASE WHEN (profits>0 and profits <=100) 
               THEN 'Met Requirements'
            WHEN (profits>100) 
               THEN 'Exceeded Requirements'
            ELSE    'No Profits'
       END as rating
from
(
SELECT
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname,
    SUM(p.amount) profits
FROM employees e left join
     profits p on (e.`id` = p.`employee_id`)
GROUP BY
   e.firstname,
   e.lastname
) tbl
```

See it here on **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea40d/1)**

You could also use just one query using the aggregate function `SUM` inside the `CASE` statement, but I think that it is not elegant as the first example with subquery.

```
SELECT
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname,
    CASE WHEN (SUM(p.amount)>0 and SUM(p.amount) <=100) 
               THEN 'Met Requirements'
            WHEN (SUM(p.amount)>100) 
               THEN 'Exceeded Requirements'
            ELSE    'No Profits'
       END as rating
FROM employees e left join
     profits p on (e.id = p.employee_id)
GROUP BY
   e.firstname,
   e.lastname
```

See it here on **[SQL Fiddle Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea40d/4)**

Comment: Fwiw, I think the second query is *more* elegant than the first!

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't research about the multiple use of the same  aggregate function in a query (as on the second example), in general programming this use to be a bad pratice (call the same function multiple times). Would that decrease the performance of the query?